# Free Shipping offer

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping-methods

I have been asked to add a Free Shipping offer for a specific country to a Magento 1.7 install.

I have removed the country from the "Flat Rate" and "Table Rate" lists, and added it as the only country on "Free Shipping", but my cart still displays the shipping rate radio button with charges.

Is there something I am missing? Still learning the fiddly bits of Magento.

Comment: So you have free shipping for one country.  And How the shipping cost should be calculated for the rest of the countries?  Is it UPS live rates or?

Comment: The shipping uses Table Rates for all other countries. I have removed the one country from the multiselect box for table rates and added it as the only option for Free Shipping.

There are no third-party shipping rates.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you have disabled all unnecessary shipping methods in the global configuration. Then check website level as well.  Clear the cache.

If you are using table rates, try disable the free shopping method as well and set free shipping condition in the admin > promotions > shopping cart rules.

Also in the table rate you can set zero for given country.